# Angular: How to associate a type to a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, service, enums

We are currently in the process of reworking the user interface of our main application. It is a multi-language Angular projects that uses translation keys and a service. (ngx-translate). Our data model is vast and use a number of enums to represent statuses and other similar values.

To map theses enum values to a key, we used a `PipeTransform` class that maps the enum value to a key and translates it. In theory, it should have worked fine. In practice, however, it forced us to create a custom input component for each of the enums that needed one with an html pattern that looked somewhat like this:

```
<select [ngModel]="model">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined">...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let value of ENUM_VALUES" //imported constant of the enum values
                [ngValue]="method">{{value | EnumValuePipe}}</option>
</select>
```

Now, in the new UI-KIT, I intended to create a new generic select form input component that was able to dynamically inject the appropriate service depending on the enum received.

The primary design worked fine but the injection of service was left to-do until now. I've been working on a few days and I come up with this code:

```
export interface Transform extends PipeTransform {}

export const TransformServiceRegistry: Map<string, { new(): Transform }> = new Map<string, { new(): Transform }>();

export const TRANSFORM_SERVICE_REGISTRY = new InjectionToken('TRANSFORM_SERVICE_REGISTRY', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => TransformServiceRegistry
});

@Injectable()
export class TransformService {
  constructor(private _injector: Injector,
              @Inject(TRANSFORM_SERVICE_REGISTRY) private _registry: Object) {
  }

  getService(name: string): any {
    const transformRegistry = this._registry as Map<string, Type<{ new(): Transform }>>;
    const type = transformRegistry.get(name);
    const transform = this._injector.get(type);

    if (isNullOrUndefined(transform))  {
      throw new Error(`Transform name was not a valid transform name`);
    }

    return transform;
  }
}
```

It is working well, assuming the registry has all the map contains every service we need. And this is where the service fails:

- I haven't found a way to populate the map dynamically at the launch of the app without doing it manually or breaking modularity (the service is part of the UI-KIT, and if it's intended to be an independent framework for other projects, thus it shouldn't import anything from the app).
- To make matters worse, it also only work with objects name for now, not with enums.

Is there any way, in Angular, that I can create this map of enums, services and values?